# Actionscript 2.0 Apply sound on keydown

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript-2

I am coding a Flash app in AS2 and I need help. I want it so that when my character jumps, a sound effect can be heard. Here is what I've tried.

```
if (Key.isDown(Key.UP) {
    jump.wav.start();
}
```

This code is applied on character. There is other code applied on my character, [here it is](http://pastebin.com/B4fwrP0Q).  The instance name of the character is `char`.

I was exploring on the internet for about 20 minutes and nothing I tried works. 
The name of sound is `jump` and it is a **.wav** file.

I think that I wrote all that I need.

Every answer is very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

To play a sound when the `Key.UP` is down on your character, you can use [`attachSound()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001514.html) method like this :

```
if (Key.isDown(Key.UP)) {
    sound = new Sound(this);
    // where "jump_sound" is the AS linkage identifier of your sound
    sound.attachSound('jump_sound');     
    sound.start(0, 1);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Yep, i tried that and more similar codes, everybody says they works, but for me character doesn't move, like it doesn't have any action. Thanks for answer, i think it is correct, but it didn't helped me. Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan Really I don't understand what's your problem, my sample code is just to play a sound and not to move a character, you have to use it in your code !